При нажатии на кнопку = в приложении калькулятора, заместо того, чтобы производить вычисления, кнопка выводится на экран
Вот сам код приложения
HTML:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
            <div class="calculator">
                <div class="calculator-value">
                    <p>0</p>
                </div>
                <div class="calculator-buttons">
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-clear button">AC</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-plusminus button">+/-</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-percent button">%</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-divide button">/</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-seven button">7</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-eight button">8</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-nine button">9</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-multiply button">x</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-four button">4</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-five button">5</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-six button">6</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-minus button">-</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-one button">1</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-two button">2</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-three button">3</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-plus button">+</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button calculator-button_zero">
                        <button class="calculator-button-zero button">0</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button">
                        <button class="calculator-button-dot button">,</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator-button ">
                        <button class="calculator-button-equal button">=</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

const buttons = document.querySelector('.calculator-buttons')
const calcValue = document.querySelector('.calculator-value p')
const clearButton = document.querySelector('.calculator-button-clear')

let firstNum = '';
let secNum = '';
let sign = ''
let finish = false
const digit = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ',']
const signs = ['+', '-', 'x', '/', '=']
function clearAll() {
    firstNum = ''
    secNum = ''
    sign = ''
    finish = false
    calcValue.textContent = 0
}

clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearAll)

buttons.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    
    if (evt.target.classList.contains('calculator-button-clear')) return
    if (!evt.target.classList.contains('button')) return
        calcValue.textContent = ''
        const key = evt.target.textContent;
        if (digit.includes(key)){
            if(secNum === '' && sign === ''){
                firstNum += key
                calcValue.textContent = firstNum
            } else if (firstNum !== '' && secNum !== '' && finish){
                secNum = key
                finish = false
                calcValue.textContent = firstNum
            } 
            else {
                secNum += key
                calcValue.textContent = secNum
            }
            return
        }
        if (signs.includes(key)){
            sign = key;
            calcValue.textContent = sign
            return
        }
        if(key === '=') {
      switch (sign) {
        case "+":
          firstNum = +firstNum + +secNum;
          break;
        case "-":
          firstNum = firstNum - secNum;
          break;
        case "x":
          firstNum = firstNum * secNum;
          break;
        case "/":
          firstNum = firstNum / secNum;
          break;
      }
            finish = true
            calcValue.textContent = firstNum
        }
    }
)

Если убрать условную конструкцию if (key === '='), то вычисления срабатывают, но без нажатия на равно. Если же ее оставить, то при нажатии на знак он просто появляется на экране. Что тут не так?

Добавьте html, с ним будет понятнее

Всё,   добавлено.

у Вас signs  содержит = ,   if (signs.includes(key))  при = внутри вызовет return, и до следующего if(key === '=') не дойдет

Благодарю) исправил массив signs, все заработало
